# How to set CORS headers on google scripts side?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Error image]

I am trying to give access to my page to send data from my form to google sheets. I use simple form and it only does GET request to google API with some parameters.

After the request is send I get status 200 but with that I also get CORS error

I read that I supposed to give permission on Google Cloud, but could not do that

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Consider using [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) to serve data from Google apps scripts. This can serve text/json/jsonp, some of which are excluded from the CORS protocol.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out!

Just `return ContentService.createTextOutput()`  in your doGet or doPost

Comment: I was expecting to see how to set the headers to allow origin, like the question said, so CORS won't bark.